# Comment syntax in jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jsp-tags

I got some (much) jsp files with comment code at the beginning.

It looks

```
<%-------------------------------------------%>
<%-- All the comment text about the author --%>
<%-- And of course the company --------------%>
<%-------------------------------------------%>
```

I installed the appication on an Tomcat 7.0.30 and get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /path/to/jsp/file.jsp 
(line: 13, column: 4) Unterminated &lt;%-- tag
```

The **LAST** comment line is the line 13!
When I change the comment code of line 13 to

```
<%-- ----------- --%>
```

all work fine!

Question1:
Why is the line 1 not a problem? **Edit:** Because it is terminated in line 2!

Question2:
Is it wright that <%-------%> is "not allowed" as a comment?

Comment: It´s strange... I did a few test with comments. Now I can´t reproduce it... maybe some wired encoding stuff or somthing... because I copied the code with nsis ...

Answer (score 0):

`<%-------%>` is allowed as a comment as I tried it myself.